# if loop processing efficiency

Tags: java, performance

Which of the 2 is better from a processing or optimizing point of view?

I feel Option 1 is more readable, but I've been told Option 2 is more efficient. Is that so?

```
if (value != null) {
    if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(ApplicationConstants.A)) {
    } else if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(ApplicationConstants.B)) {
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
if ((value != null) && (value.equalsIgnoreCase(ApplicationConstants.A))) {

} else if ((value != null) && (value.equalsIgnoreCase(ApplicationConstants.B))) {

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing here to care about performance wise, write your code so it's as readable as you can make it.

When performance testing later highlights areas that need to be optimized then and only then optimize only the places that need it.

To make it more readable you can invert your tests to get rid of the null check:

```
if (ApplicationConstants.A.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
} else if (ApplicationConstants.B.equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
}
```

Comment: +1 agree, the difference here is so minimal it won't matter nearly 100% of the time. Optimize for readability.

Comment: I'd even bet there probably won't be any difference at all after the hotspot optimizer ran.

Answer (score 2):

`Option 1` is efficient since there is no redundant `null` check.

Comment: Thankfully, ifnonnull gets its own JVM opcode so the comparison is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect the first to be slightly more efficient, because `&&` is short-circuit, so it gives multiple conditional branches anyway. But if you want to be certain, time them.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option 1 as in option 2, more no of comparisons are made.

Comment: Yeah and as Thomas pointed out, there is nothing called an If loops, loops would be for, while, do while, for each and for in...

Answer (score 0):

The first option is better as with one condition check you can decide.
so if value != null then only it will enter else it will not even enter the conditional block.
But in 2nd option it will check if condition , and if false also it wd check else condition (for value == null).